# JWT auth for NATS in nestjs

Tags: typescript, nestjs, nats.io

I'm trying to integrate [JWT auth(orization) for NATS](https://docs.nats.io/nats-server/configuration/securing_nats/jwt) message broker into nestjs, where I use nestjs app on both sides ([requester & responder](https://dev.to/nestjs/integrate-nestjs-with-external-services-using-microservice-transporters-part-2-3hgd)). If I understand correctly there are two parts necessary to make it work with nestjs:

- modify the nest NATS client to forward [missing options](https://github.com/nats-io/nats.js#new-authentication-nkeys-and-user-credentials) (userJWT and nonceSigner callback),
- include the logic to [create NATS users](https://github.com/nats-io/nkeys.js#basic-usage) and return it from custom auth API.

How can I easily extend the nestjs NATS client to include the missing client options?
Affected parts seem to be `NatsOptions`, `ClientOptions`, `ClientNats` & `ClientProxy`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you already have access to these options without the need to extend the nestjs NATS Client.

Nestjs destructures the NatsOptions object into the Client connection options, see reference code here https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/microservices/server/server-nats.ts#L69-L76

And reference code for the full NatsOptions Interface here: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/097afb0884415ee98910d93380b3eb6592cfb03c/packages/microservices/interfaces/microservice-configuration.interface.ts#L103

Comment: Thanks, yes, I've made a PR to include the properties that were missing at that time